# How to measure the data usage of my app in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-data-usage

I have a react-native app that I want to measure the data usage per user and gather them to optimize it later.

I saw old questions for native android suggesting that trafficStats may give stats by UUID.

What possibilities are there for react-native?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using react-native means that you have two options,

1. The native implementation which depends on the OS you're working on.
2. If you're using a JS library for networking (Axios) or even a builtin function (fetch) you can implement a wrapper Promise which calculates the length of any input/output string, + an approximation of the length of the header.

Comment: But we are also downloading video files, does this apply to them too?

Comment: Also, please check here: https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo/issues/388